# Binary classifier with input tuple

Tags: python, classification

I want to create a classifier that given a tuple (in my case, a user and an artist in my "social network"), is able to test whether the two are compatible or not (in my case, whether the user will listen to the artist).

In itself, it's not a complicated problem, but I lack the knowledge and experience to make it work.

I thought about makind a dataframe of users, and extrapolate metrics for them, to obtain something like this:

```
users = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.6],
                      [2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.3],
                      [3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7],
                     columns=['userID', 'metric1', 'metric2', 'metric3'])
```

And to test whether the artist is present in the list of listened artists or not as the boolean output feature. This means that for each artist I want to test I need to create a new model:

```
users['outcome'] = test1_values

train, test = train_test_split(users, train_size=0.8)

X_train = train[train.columns.difference(['outcome'])]
y_train = train['dimissione']

X_test = test[test.columns.difference(['outcome'])]
y_test = test['dimissione']

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This may work, but I was wondering if there are better alternatives.

Especially since I wanted to incorporate metrics also on the artists side, for example its popularity or the popularity of its genre, as well as the amount of friends who already listen to it.
Should I calculate those quantities before building the model and test one artist at a time?

Any input is appreciated, thank you.